# Is Casimir's Sail possible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, casimir-effect

In the Casimir effect, the pressure of virtual particles between parallel plates, that are very close to each other is less then the pressure in free vacuum.

Is it possible then to make "a sail" on this effect - create some material, where one side is full of these microscopic plates, and therefore the pressure on this side will be less, and the result would be a "perpetual motion machine" without breaking physic laws, because the energy is taken from quantum fluctuations?

Comment: Sure, the casimir force causes two plates to attract one another. But if both plates are fastened to the same object then the net force on the object is zero. Its center-of-mass will not accelerate. So you could not make a sail this way.

Comment: @Diffycue That seems like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Diffycue We strongly discourage answering in comments.  Comments can be removed without notice and also note that upvotes on answers gets more reputation points than you'll get from a comment.

Comment: How is this different from bootstrapping (self lifting yourself)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the casimir force causes two plates to attract one another. But if both plates are fastened to the same object then the net force on the object is zero. Its center-of-mass will not accelerate. So you could not make a sail this way. Even though the origin of the force is in the vacuum fluctuations between the plates, it remains the case that the two plates pull each other with equal and opposite forces. So if they are each stationed on the same vessel the net force on the vessel due to the plates cancels.

Comment: how does Casimir force work on the plane, what is perpendicular to the plates?